# Include() in LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following models in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class TaskStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

For reference, here is my **DbContext** class:

```
public class TaskManagerSets : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Task> TaskSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaskStatus> TaskStatusSet { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a *List* Action in my **TaskController**:

```
TaskManagerSets dbcontext = new TaskManagerSets();
public ActionResult List()
{
    var tasks = from tsk in dbcontext.TaskSet.Include("TaskStatusSet")
                select tsk;
    return View(tasks.ToList());
}
```

Finally I have the Task List View:

```
 @model IEnumerable<TaskManager.Models.Task>

 <ul>
 @foreach (var tsk in Model) 
 { 
    <li>@tsk.Id | @tsk.CreatedOn | @tsk.Status.Description</li> 
 } 
 </ul>
```

When I execute my project I get the following error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'CodeFirstNamespace.Task' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'TaskStatus'.

The problem is definitely on the `Include("TaskStatusSet")` but how should I fix this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Since you are working with the `DbContext` API the best option is to use the type-safe overload of Include:
using System.Data.Entity;

```
// You must add a using statement for this namespace to have the following 
// lambda version of Include available

//...

var tasks = from tsk in dbcontext.TaskSet.Include(t => t.Status)
            select tsk;
```

You will get Intellisense and compile-time checks which helps to avoid issues with wrong strings like you had.

The less satisfactory, NON-type-safe technique would be:

```
var tasks = from tsk in dbcontext.TaskSet.Include("Status")
            select tsk;
```

Note: the presented order of the techniques has been changed, so keep this in mind when reading comments.

Comment: The first suggestion works like a charm, but I didn't manage to get the second working. This solves my problem, but the second way would be more elegant and robust. Thank you.

Comment: @nunaxe: It definitely should work. Include has an overload with a parameter `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path`.

Comment: Oh, I just see that you `CTP4` in your tags. Are you still using CTP4 version? Perhaps this overload didn't exist in this old version. Current version is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx

Comment: You have to include the namespace `System.Data.Entity` for getting the typed version to compile.

Comment: @Slauma: Could you add Jan's comment (System.Data.Entity) to your answer?

Comment: @jan, thanks about your comment, should be included on answer!

Comment: How would this work, if Status had a nested entity also, and you wanted that  as well?    Managers > Employees > Permissions    sort of scenario?

Comment: @Slauma Please I have another question , if there is multiple relations with multiple tables how I can make .include() with multiple columns in different tables suppose I need to bring name from another table is it correct like this dbcontext.TaskSet.Include(t => t.Status , p => p.Name)    ???