# Navigation property not getting filled on lazy loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying my hands-on  on mvc examples given on  Mvc Offical Site.
Here i have 3 Models Student,Course and Enrollment where there is an one to many relationship on Course and Enrollment entities and  many to one relationship on Enrollment and student.

The models for Student,Course and Enrollment are as follows with the navigation properties marked as "virtual" since i need to perform lazy binding

```
 public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get;set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

In the same way i have my course model

My Enrollment Model

```
 public class Enrollment
    {
        public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
       // public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using Code-First Technique With EF 5.My DB Context Class is as follows

```
 public class SchoolContext:DbContext
    {


        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

By Scaffolding I have generated all  my views .On Click of my details Action link I have a controller function that is called

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {

            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true; 
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
           // db.Entry(student).Reference(p => p.Enrollments).Load();
           IEnumerable<Enrollment> s= student.Enrollments;
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

Here the problem is when the Find() method is called in the controller the navigation property in Student Class model is null.But there is data in DB corresponding to the id that is being passed.In short,the navigation property is not returning data(null).

Comment: use `.Include()` ... refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661771/what-does-include-do-in-linq) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648154/include-in-linq-to-entities-query) posts.

Comment: That's fine.....But I prefer Lazy loading.Could you please tell me where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: Try amending your Student class, by creating a constructor and adding the following .. Enrollments = new Hashset<Enrollment>();

Answer (score 0):

You have to materialize the entities to get a rid of the current lazy loading in the query:

```
Student student = db.Students.Find(id).ToList();
```

This will fix your problem without ToList() after db.Students.Find(id); = will returns the  generated object from the dynamic proxy.

Second problem you have a casting bug:

```
IEnumerable<Enrollment> enrollments = student.Enrollments; // is wrong
```

should be:

```
ICollection<State> enrollments = student.Enrollments;
```

or

```
var enrollments = student.Enrollments;
```

Comment: I am not clear about this answer.Could you please elaborate..Here Find() method returns an object of type Student and casting it to an Enumerable type throws an compile time error.