# Getting related data from viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having trouble getting a value for some related data using Entity Framework. The basic premise is that a 'property' belongs to a single 'community', and a 'community' belongs to a single 'region'

i have the following model for my property:

```
public class Property
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CommunityID { get; set; }

    public int PropertyTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

}
```

and for my community model..

```
public class Community
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Region Region { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

and for my region...

```
public class Region
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Community> Communities { get; set; }
}
```

I have pulled all this together in a viewmodel...

```
public class PropertyDetailViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

However, the issue occurs when trying to push that into a view using the following controller method:

```
Property property = await db.Property.FindAsync(id);
var viewModel = new PropertyDetailViewModel
{
    Name = property.Name,
    Community = property.Community,
    Region = property.Community.Region
};
return View(viewModel);
```

In my view, i am creating a placeholder for the Region Name using

> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region.Name)

But this is showing as empty, even though there is definitely valid entries in the database?

Comment: having entries in DB is one thing are you populating the property on your view model? did you debug it to see if values are being set?

Comment: The tutorial's i've been reading seem to use virtual properties. After a quick search online, it seems to be more efficient when calling the database because it uses lazy loading.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Let me give it a try and i'll let you know how i get on. Thank you

Comment: @Gavin5511 - Make sure you understand the drawbacks of eager loading before accepting that as your best option.  By removing the virtual keyword from the Region navigation property you will be loading the entire Region object every time you load a Property entity anywhere in your system.  Assuming Region is a small entity or is always used when a Property is loaded, this might not be a problem.  But imagine that Region is a huge entity with lots of properties and other related data.  You might not want to load the entire Region object each time a Property is loaded. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks @chambo, i understand. In fact, i've now fixed the problem, and it was quite the opposite. If you look at my models above, the viewmodel was using a virtual property, but my data model wasn't. I've not changed both to use virtual, and it is working perfectly. I don't know why that might have fixed it though? Maybe having a mis-match was confusing it?

Comment: @Gavin5511 - `virtual` on your view model would have no impact on loading data from your entity class.  Adding `virtual` to your entity class Region property made it lazy loading allowing it to load the data from the Region entity when you mapped your Property object to the view model.  I suggest [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) as further reading

Comment: Thank you. If you care to summarize that into an answer, i'll happily accept it. Otherwise, i'll detail the changes and mark my own answer as accepted. Thank you very much, that has cleared a lot up, and i did not know that adding virtual on the view model would have made no impact :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use include so your region will not null.

```
Property property = await db.Property.Include(p => p.Community.Region).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == id);
```

More detailed: [Include() in LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648154/include-in-linq-to-entities-query#5650732)

Answer (score 0):

Try flattening the Region object out in your view model to only use the fields  you need:

```
public class PropertyDetailViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

    public string RegionName { get; set; }
}
```

Then update your view model mapping code:

```
Property property = await db.Property.FindAsync(id);
var viewModel = new PropertyDetailViewModel
{
    Name = property.Name,
    Community = property.Community,
    RegionName = property.Community.Region.Name
};
return View(viewModel);
```

Finally update your view to use the flattened RegionName property in the view model:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RegionName)
```

Use this in conjunction with `.Include()` in a query statement to improve performance